# Handling concurrent XML writings and readings from ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml, concurrency, file-access

Each time a users visits my web site pages, several `xml` elements are written and removed from one predefined file.

Eventually there will be a situation, when on this same file a read and write operation will take place almost simultaniously. How do I handle concurrency in this case? Is there a special base class library class that can handle it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML files will not do this for you.  You could set up a synchronizing object: the simplest would be to have a common function that accesses the file and use the lock key word.  Use a Mutex for inter-process synchronization.

However, this will be a potential bottle neck.

It may be time to start using a database.